# JavaScript error in using "this" and "onclick" - Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Tags: javascript

As I'm learning the "this" keyword in JavaScript, I've written some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<style>
h1 {
  color:red;
}
</style>
<body>
<script>

function doSomething() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
}

</script>
<div onclick="doSomething(this)">
   <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
</div>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I click on the div, it didn't hide, and the console gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
```

I've also tried to attach the click event to the h1 tag, but it also didn't work. Any idea on what's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: How do you expect `doSomething` to do anything when you haven't passed in an argument in your function definition?

Comment: Your function doesn't have a parameter, so why are you passing something to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onclick="doSomething(this)"` is going to call `doSomething`, passing in a `this` as an argument, `this` being a reference to the `div` element.

`doSomething` isn't accepting any arguments. However, in order for this to work, it needs to accept arguments, like the following, for example:

```js
function doSomething(referenceToTheElement) {
  referenceToTheElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="doSomething(this)">
  <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
</div>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because you didn't specify it as input to the function (when defining the function), but JavaScript can still work with these extra inputs. All of the inputs are of a JavaScript function is stored in an array called arguments. So, instead of writing

this.style.display = 'none';

Use this

arguments[0].style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword is related to the execution context of the current function. However, it does not pass on to any functions called by that function.

Consider the following code:

```js
var obj = {
   MyMethod: function () {
      alert("MyMethod - this == obj is " + (this == obj));
      MyGlobal();
   }
}
obj.MyMethod();

function MyGlobal() {
   alert("MyGlobal - this == obj is " + (this == obj));
}
```

In this example, `obj` is an object with a method named `MyMethod`. Inside that method it calls the global function `MyGlobal`. The alerts will tell you that `this` refers to `obj` inside `MyMethod`, but not in `MyGlobal`.

How does this apply to your example? Well, when you write HTML like this:

```
<div onclick="doSomething()">...</div>
```

That translates into JavaScript like this:

```
[div].onclick = function () { doSomething(); };
```

The markup is essentially translated into an anonymous function and assigned to the `onclick` method of your HTML object (the `div` in this case).

This means that `this` refers to the `div` element within your anonymous function, but not in `doSomething`. Because of that, you can refer to `this` in your markup and pass it into `doSomething` like this:

```
<div onclick="doSomething(this)">...</div>
```

Since this is equivalent to this JavaScript:

```
[div].onclick = function () { doSomething(this); };
```

Try changing your original code like this:

```
<div id="ClickMe">
   <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
</div>
<script>

function doSomething() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('ClickMe').onclick = doSomething;

</script>
```

Since you are assigning `doSomething` directly to the HTML element, `this` will now refer to that element.